# Is the set of escaping endpoints for $e^z-2$ completely metrizable?

Tags: gn.general-topology, ds.dynamical-systems, complex-dynamics

Let $f:\mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ be the complex exponential $$f(z)=e^z-2.$$  It is known that $J(f)$, the Julia set of $f$, is a  uncountable collection of disjoint rays (one-to-one continuous images of $[0,\infty)$).  It looks something like the figure below. The number $2$ is rather arbitrary; the dynamics of $f$ are practically identical if we replace $2$ with any number greater than $1$.

[image]

Let $E(f)$ be the set of all $0$-endpoints of these rays, i.e. the "endpoints" of $J(f)$.

Let $I(f)=\{z\in \mathbb C:f^n(z)\to\infty\}$. Here $f^2$ is the composition $f\circ f$, etc.

Let  $\tilde E(f)=I(f)\cap E(f)$ be the set of *escaping endpoints* of $J(f)$.

It is known that $E(f)$ is completely metrizable.

**Question.** Is $\tilde E(f)$ completely metrizable?

We may independently consider the set of escaping points. 
It is easy to show $I(f)$ is an $F_{\sigma\delta}$-subset of the plane using only continuity of $f$.

**Question.** Is $I(f)$ completely metrizable?

---

*Alhabib, Nada; Rempe-Gillen, Lasse*, [**Escaping endpoints explode**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s40315-016-0169-8), Comput. Methods Funct. Theory 17, No. 1, 65-100 (2017). [ZBL1381.37051](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1381.37051). for further information.

Comment: A subset of a complete metric space is completely metrizable if and only if it is a $G_\delta$, so the questions are equivalent to ask whether these sets are $G_\delta$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\tilde E(f)$ and $I(f)$ are first category, so the answer to each question is **NO**. https://doi.org/10.1017/etds.2019.111